# Next js When i Clicked <Link> of next/link, in _app.js Error invoked. About data fetch

Tags: reactjs, next.js

#### Hi there:) It is about `_app.js` and `<Link>` of next/link

### - Question(like title)

#### When i Clicked   of next/link, in `_app.js` Error invoked.

#### About Error is it `Can't Get Fetch Data` like below.

[image]

#### But, when before click(first page), It doesn`t make problem.

#### That data is `<Header>`'s data,

#### So i implemented data fetch code in `getInitalProps()` in _app.js(container of common things)

#### Cause I've known `_app.js` is common container, common thing like `<Header>` things always render

#### even navigating other /pages/[location].. But that`s error occured..

#### What i know is wrong..?(or Is functional _app.js problem? )

## 1. root/pages/_app.js

```
// root/pages/_app.js
const App = ({ Component, pageProps, datas }) => {
    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Header data={datas} />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <Footer data={datas} />
            </Provider>
        </div>

    )
}

App.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, res, ctx }) => {

    let pageProps = {}
    let gnb_menu;
    console.log(Component.getInitialProps);
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        gnb_menu = await axios.get([data url something]);
    }
    return {
        pageProps,
        datas: gnb_menu.data.menu,
    }
}

export default App;
```

## 2.  root/src/components/header/Header.js

```
<Link
  href={`/category`}
  as={`/category`}
>
```

## 3. root/pages/category/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Content = () => {
    console.log('contentsss');
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id, content } = router.query

    return (
        <div>
            ca/contents
            <h1>{id}</h1>
            <h2>{content}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Content
```

thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getInitialProps` function allows `gnb_menu` to be accessed without being initialized. `gnb_menu` is only set if `Component.getInitialProps` is defined. If it is not, then `gnb_menu` will remain undefined and you will get `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` because `gnb_menu.data.menu` is not possible to process.

Try adding a `console.log` as shown below to get an idea of what comes back from your `axios.get` call, or if it even executes it at all. That should give you hints as to what is going wrong.

```
App.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, res, ctx }) => {
    let pageProps = {}
    let gnb_menu;
    console.log(Component.getInitialProps);   // <-- what did this display?
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
        gnb_menu = await axios.get([data url something]);
        console.log(">>>gnb_menu",gnb_menu);  // <-- does this show anything?
    }
    return {
        pageProps,
        datas: gnb_menu.data.menu,
    }
}
```

In any case you have an unsafe situation because you leave `gnb_menu` undefined and allow a code path where it's never set before trying to access it.  If it's possible that `Component.getInitialProps` doesn't exist, then maybe you want to return a default value like this:

```
return { 
  pageProps, 
  datas: gnb_menu && gnb_menu.data ? gnb_menu.data.menu : null
}
```

Comment: Above all, I really appreciate your answer!
In first page 
console.log(Component.getInitialProps);   // <-- what did this display?
displays function(){...}
and when i click That <Link>
that
console.log(Component.getInitialProps);   // <-- what did this display?
displays undefined.
You correct! Cause Component.getInitialProps undefined, that problem occur.
Then... Let me know How can i get Component.getInitialProps when i click <Link> in /root/components/header/Header.js ..?

Comment: the `getInitialProps` value will depend on the component being rendered. Does the component your link tries to go to define this function?

Comment: The Component containing <Link> doesn`t have getInitialProps(). Because That component is located in 'root/components/...' not 'pages' directory.
I heard getInitialProps must be used in 'pages'..
Then, i must relocate <Link> Component to 'pages'...?